# Is it possible to start playing with JavaFX MadiaPlayer without latency

Tags: javafx, mp4

I need to play mp4 files one after another without latency (less than 5-10ms). I don't want to use vlc or xugler.

May be there is some solution to make player wait for my trigger.notify() after play() with injection of code (but MediaPlayer is final):

```
Object trigger = new Object();
synchronized (trigger) {
    trigger.wait();
}
```

I need [AudioClip](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) but for mp4 file.

Answer (score 0):

I retested MediaPlayer. Now I waited for READY state and started playing. Latency was 3-12ms. It's not very good but it's acceptable.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (mediaPlayer.getStatus() != MediaPlayer.Status.READY) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sleep was interrupted.");
        }
    }
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mediaPlayer.play();
    while (mediaPlayer.getStatus() != MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING) {}
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("latency " +(after - before));
}).start();
```